# Callback function on Android

Tags: java, android, callback, android-volley

In java 8 there are the new Lambda functions and method references. Are there something similar on android? Using volley I need to pass a callback function to handle the onResponse, what's the best way to handle this?

Comment: as far as I know, Android doesn't support java 8, so you are stuck with anonymous classes  !!

Comment: So how can handle the problem? Should I write a Callback class with the callback methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing it like this: Place all volley callings in api file which is called from Application singleton,

```
    public Request<?> getMessage(int messageId, boolean maxBodySize, Response.Listener<MessageData> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    String url = apiURL + MESSAGE + "?";
    int method = Request.Method.GET;
    GsonRequest<MessageData> request = new GsonRequest<MessageData>(
            method,
            url,
            MessageData.class,
            null,
            responseListener,
            errorListener,
            gson) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    return mQueue.add(request);
}
```

Call it from where ever you want with:

```
    getApi().getMessage(messageNumber, true,
                    new Response.Listener<MessageData>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(MessageData data) {

                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            resolveResponseStatus(error);
                        }

                    }
            );
```

Comment: Great, it looks a nice way to do that